# Programmatically Triggering CloudWatch Events From Inside AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I wrote an AWS lambda that processes data from S3 and gets some result X (map String -> Date). Now I wanted to send the result X as a custom CloudWatch Event event so a CloudWatch Alarm can pick the event and trigger the alarm so the person addressing the alarm can see the result X.

I am stuck on how to programmatically send an event (CloudWatch Event) to CloudWatch so CloudWatch Alarm can pick it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`putEvents` from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-cloudwatch-send-events.html:

```
CloudWatchEventsClient cwe =
        CloudWatchEventsClient.builder().build();

final String EVENT_DETAILS =
    "{ \"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\" }";

PutEventsRequestEntry request_entry = PutEventsRequestEntry.builder()
    .detail(EVENT_DETAILS)
    .detailType("sampleSubmitted")
    .resources(resource_arn)
    .source("aws-sdk-java-cloudwatch-example").build();

PutEventsRequest request = PutEventsRequest.builder()
    .entries(request_entry).build();

PutEventsResponse response = cwe.putEvents(request);
```

Comment: +1 thanks @Horatiu Jeflea. I was able to get a success response result:{FailedEntryCount: 0,Entries: [{EventId: cfa74278-6d26-871a-895c-806873c39f2c,}]} but in cloudwatch I was not able to find the event in cloudwatch to be able to attach it to cloudwatch Alarm. Is that even possible?